# cutting a trapezium (or whatever) in multiple pieces of same size

Tags: python, list

I am just using python occasionally at the moment, so I don't get what's wrong with this code:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
xpos = list([])
for i in range(6):
    xp = solve(6*x+22/32*x**2-544/6*(i+1),x)
    xpos.append(xp)
xpos1 = list([])    
for i in range(len(xpos)):
    xpos1.append(xpos[i][1])
```

It should give me a list with the x positions that will cut the trapezium into pieces of same size... The problem is that the list `xpos1` is first created as empty list and then it is deleted within the last line of the code. When I change the last line to

```
xpos1.append(xpos[i])
```

`xpos1` is created (as copy of xpos, of course). What is wrong with the code, I don't get it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does the script run if you remove the last 3 lines? Also you do not need to do ` xpos = list([])`, this will do fine: `xpos = []`. Finally, what objest does solve return? a tuple? If it is just a number `xpos[i][1]` will return an error.

Comment: xpos = [] did not work...dont know why. xpos is a list with size 6*2, xpos[1][1] returns the value i am looking for. xpos1.append(xpos[1][1]) works fine, too...just in combination with the loop it doenst work

Comment: I copied your code but upon calling `xpos[1][1]` I get an `IndexError`. Did you mean to write `xpos[1][0]`? If i print `xpos` I get `[[15], [30], [45], [60], [75], [90]]`

Comment: for xpos i get [-16.6485909908557, 7.92131826358296]
[-21.1802620082663, 12.4529892809936]
[-24.7272727272727, 16.0000000000000]
[-27.7421836630132, 19.0149109357405]
[-30.4104262178197, 21.6831534905470]
[-32.8296520593177, 24.1023793320450]

Comment: I'm not getting that, I've updated my sympy up to v1.0. Are there prior codes which you are not copying?

Comment: no...this is the first code for me on a new system...perhaps there is something wrong withe the preferences?!

Comment: Are you using python3?

Comment: What you want to get is a list made from the second element in xpos, right ? (like : [7.92131826358296, 12.4529892809936, 16.0000000000000, 19.0149109357405, 21.6831534905470, 24.1023793320450] )

Comment: exactly...any ideas? Thx for your help!

Comment: instead of last 3 lines do: `xpos1 = [y[1] for y in xpos]`

Comment: Actually I ran your code in python3, it works fine

Comment: Maybe try printing it out? Just append this to the end of your code: `print(xpos1)`

Comment: @EV.Kounis...same problem, variable is not shown in variable explorer. Printing does work...i dont get it :)

Comment: @derh The variable is not deleted, unless you print it out you will not see the contents of the list. Once the script finishes running only then will the variables be deleted

Comment: anyway, i will try it at home again...just dont get it. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing out the variable before the script terminates:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
xpos = list([])
for i in range(6):
    xp = solve(6*x+22/32*x**2-544/6*(i+1),x)
    xpos.append(xp)
xpos1 = list([])    
for i in range(len(xpos)):
    xpos1.append(xpos[i][1])

print(xpos1)
```

That way you will see the contents of the list.

Comment: printing works fine, but i need the values for further calculation

Comment: Please add more of the code you are executing so we can do a proper investigation into it. As of right now the script works fine according to my tests

Comment: it realy is the whole script...i just wanted to do a quick calculation :)

Comment: Are you using this script with another python script? Because variables don't transfer over different script executions.

Comment: no...just the exact code...i just want to manually put the numbers into a cad-program.

Comment: So then it's all fine. Since you said that printing works and that you manually put the number into a CAD program and now you have the values printed, can we say it is resolved?

Comment: hehe, yes we can. but i am still wondering whats happening here

Comment: Please select an answer by accepting the one which is most relevant or helpful to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tested on Python3, with the latest version of sympy installed through `pip3 install sympy`
And I don't see what is going wrong in your code, as it works on my computer.
I would only suggest an alternative approach to creating the list xpos1 :

```
xpos1 = [xp[1] for xp in xpos]
```

Using this line, instead, I get the desired result.